# Can't declare a variable in a MySQL Function

Tags: mysql, sql, function, syntax, declare

I have been trying to write a function that retrieves an employees pay rate on a specific date; however I keep running into a syntax error which I cannot figure out.

**Here is my code:**

```
create function rate_on_date(staff_id INT, given_date DATE) 
    returns float
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE hour_rate float;

    SELECT DISTINCT salarygrade.HOURLYRATE STATUS INTO hour_rate
    FROM salarygrade JOIN staffongrade
    ON  salarygrade.GRADE = staffongrade.GRADE
    WHERE staff_id = staffongrade.STAFFNO 
    AND given_date BETWEEN staffongrade.STARTDATE AND staffongrade.FINISHDATE;

RETURN hour_rate;

END //
```

**Here is the error message:**

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near " at line 5

Comment: Did you remember to change the delimiter (using e.g. `DELIMITER //`) *before* attempting to define the function?

Comment: I did, just forgot to include it above. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you do that there is no syntax error in your function.

Comment: Turns out, I wasn't running the delimiter code with the function! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: No worries. I'm glad you got it sorted.